# setting variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I need to create on snippet of javascript that, based on an A tags id, the window will navigate to the proper html file. I've got something together that when I look at it, it should work but for some reason it doesnt. Here's what I got.

```
<script> 
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function() { 
        $('a').each(function (index){
            var elementId = $(this).attr("id"); 
            elementId= elementId + '.html';
            $(function(){ 
                $(elementId).click(function (event) { 
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    window.location.assign(elementId); 
                }); 
            }); 
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

This part is so that I can load an external html in an ios web app with out exiting the web app window

```
$(function(){ $(elementId).click(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    window.location.assign(elementId);
```

Did I write the variable wrong some how? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in your code sample? It's hard to tell what's really going on when it's formatted like this.

Comment: Now what is that DOM ready function doing in there ?

Comment: The DOM ready function is there to run the code when my first page is loaded. It may not be the proper way to do it, but I have a variation of this where there is no variable and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.assign(this.id + '.html'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this would replace all of his script and not just the inner portion he highlighted, correct?

Comment: Awesome, it works. Only had to change the 'a.html' to 'a' but it works. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of what you have there...

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("a").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = this.id + ".html";
        });
    });
</script>
```